# Mobx computed not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, mobx, mobx-react

`mobx` getter does not seem to react to changes in localStorage.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);

    this.setCount = this.setCount.bind(this);
  }

  private static _instance: Test;
  static get instance(): Test {
    if (!this._instance) {
      this._instance = new Test();
    }
    return this._instance;
  }

  get count(): number | null {
    const value: string | null = localStorage.getItem("count");
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    return JSON.parse(value);
  }

  // was 0, updating to 1
  setCount(newValue: number): void {
    localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(value));
    console.log(
      "updated count",
      newValue, // 1
      "getter local storage?",
      this.count, // 0, old value !!!!
      "direct access local storage?",
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count") ?? "null"), // 1, new value
    );
  }
}
```

`direct access local storage` after the update logs the new value, but `getter local storage`, which runs the same code behind a `mobx` computed, does not update unless a hard refresh occurs.

I have all functions in this class observable in the constructor, and the class is initialized once at the app root (logged initialization to be sure). All references use `Test.instance`, so it's not reinitializing the class.

Local storage is not async in any way, so it shouldn't lag in its update.
I'm perplexed.

I know I can just set the value as an observable and not use a computed getter to resolve this, but I'd like to know the fundamental reason behind this.

Comment: A computed updates when an observable that is referenced inside of its computation changes.  Your computed references no observables, so it does not re-run.